# Access VBA Export to New CSV Run-time Error 3011

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, export-to-csv, transfer

I have code that exports a dynamic query to a csv.  First I save the sql to an existing query, updating it's sql. Then I use that as the query defs, provide saved specs, and want to export to a dynamically constructed csv file name. The csv doesn't exist yet, so I am creating it.  I thought doing a docmd.transfertext acExportDelim would create the file.

I end up getting the following error:

```
Run-time error '3011':

The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'filename.csv'.
Make sure it is spelled correctly. If 'filename.csv' is not a local object, 
check your network connection or contact the server administrator.
```

The "filename.csv" in the error, is exactly what I construct in the below code, and the name of the csv file I want to be created by this process.

```
Private Sub cmdExportList_Click()
    Dim fsql As String
    Dim f As Form
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyDate As String
    Dim args As String
    
    Set f = Forms!frmMyLists.Form.frmMyLists_SubResults.Form
    args = Nz(Forms!frmMyLists.Form.cboMyList.Value, "00")
    
    fsql = "SELECT * " & _
            "FROM tblVFileImport "

    fsql = fsql & "WHERE tblVFileImport.ListName = '" & args & "' "
    
    fsql = fsql & "ORDER BY tblVFileImport.ID"
    
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryListExportSpecs").SQL = fsql
    
    MyDate = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")
    
    If IsDev = True Then
        vFile = "C:\LocalPath\VFileData\ExportList\" & args & MyDate & ".csv"
    Else
        vFile = "\\Server\Share\ExportList\" & args & MyDate & ".csv"
    End If
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "MyListExportSpecs", "qryListExportSpecs", vFile, True
    
    Application.FollowHyperlink vFile
    
    
    MsgBox "All Set! " & args & " tagged list is now open in Excel. Have Fun!", vbOKOnly, "Export Complete"
End Sub
```

Right now, I am in my dev copy (IsDev = True) so I'm just going to that local path.  I tried creating a csv with the name first, but if I don't write anything to it (which I don't want to, because I'm wanting to transfer the text to it) then it goes away when I close it. I am wondering if it does that because it's 0 bytes. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Edit:

I found that if I tested by creating the csv before running the code, so it would already exist, the code was deleting it. I researched that and found the export specs can sometimes mess things up. I removed the export specs and now it works!

So this is :
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "qryListExportSpecs", vFile, True

Comment: Use `Debug.Print vFile` to inspect the actual value of `vFile`.

Comment: `f` is never used. Did you want to use that as the form in the `Nz` statement?

Comment: I have done a debug on vfile. It’s the path and file name I want. There is nothing unusual about it. I use the f variable after this point to refresh the main form. I didn’t include it here, because it’s not relevant to the problem. I get the runtime error on the transfertext line.

Comment: i believe TransferText does not created the file, at least not mentioned in Microsoft documentation.